# Samsung is not honoring Warranty

Tags: warranty

I bought a directly from Samsung a PC Monitor on Nov. 2020. I did try to submit a warranty service but when I go Samsung Website it says when I enter my serial number that my device is under warranty until Oct 2023. Samsung support team replied that it is only 1 year and that is no longer under warranty. Please advise where to submit a claim for this matter.
Email sent by Samsung:
"Greetings from Samsung!

Thank you for submitting your receipt.

After carefully reviewing the Bill of Sale of your item, this device (Samsung QLED Gaming Monitor) has only a year warranty starting from the date of purchase: 11/27/2020 - 11/27/20201. If you wish to continue with the repair request, charges will apply.

Though we will not be able to proceed with this request, should you wish to discuss your warranty with us or continue with the repair with charges please call us at 1-800-726-7864 or go to our website [www.samsung.com](http://www.samsung.com)

Thank you for choosing Samsung!

All the best,

Jucelle G.

Samsung Support Team"

I reply
"I don't agree. And I want to raise this with a manager. I submitted from the Samsung site a picture that this is on warranty until October 2023. Here is my proof of warranty.  Please do your due diligence in order to validate this. It's annoying for me to go back and forth with Samsung to provide this information. If you can't do anything please raise this with a manager or supervisor."

I included two screenshots of the process I'm doing on the Samsung website by entering the serial number and another picture with the results saying that the Monitor is still under warranty.

Comment: I don't think there is a question of law here. If you can prove that you purchased a warranty that runs until 2023 then it's obviously required that they honour it. But how to persuade them of this is not a legal question.

Comment: @DJClayworth Actually there is no question at all here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legal approach to the problem is to file a lawsuit, though every sale implies a contract, and you need to check the contract to see whether you have to submit to binding arbitration instead of suing them. The DIY approach is to write the appropriate legal complaint and file it in court (and all of the other formalities), the more sensible approach is to hand that job to an attorney who will then do something on your behalf – the first step is writing a formal letter and mailing it to the right person at the company.

The most effective DIY approach is probably to state your proof that the item is still under warranty in a formal letter, and mail physical copies to customer service and perhaps the legal department. A "formal letter" states the pertinent legal facts, and doesn't get sidetracked with emotional declarations about annoyance etc (business people tend to take formal letters more seriously).

Comment: It's worth adding that a notice on Samsung's website is fairly weak evidence of whether or not the OP's warranty is longer than 1 year and OP should really check what the actual contract says about how long the warranty is.